# Docusign python example "C O N S E N T R E Q U I R E D" despite consent granted

Tags: docusignapi

Created a developer account and trying to follow the basic https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt example but cannot get it to work.  My goal is just to create a basic POC  showing the ability to download envelopes using the API as a system integration (the idea would be for this app to download ALL completed envelopes, regardless of the owning account, for local storage).

What I've done:

- Created a single developer account and sandbox, downloaded code from git
- Under APIs created a new app/integration key, generated RSA key pair, and set the redirect URI to https://www.docusign.com
- Copied all values into the config file of the code sample

When I run the code it consistently throws an error CONSENT REQUIRED and provides a link for the user to use to grant conset.  The first time this happened I followed the link, logged in, and allowed access.  On subsequent runs the link just immediately redirects to www.docusign.com.  Also, under my account Connected Apps I can see that the app I granted access to is listed, so obviously something worked...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you copy your userId (GUiD) and used it in the API call to obtain JWT Token?

Comment: Per the instructions I filled out the necessary values in ds_config.ini, which include the rsa private key, the integrator key/client id, and the user id/api username (since it seems like everything in this api has one or more names meaning the same thing.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, as mentioned when I first ran the code it provided a link to accept permissions which I accepted, and on subsequent attempts it automatically takes me to the redirect url which makes it seem like those perms have already been accepted successfully.

Comment: can you share your code? especially anything to do with the url, if you keep asking to go to the consent url - it will do it again. You only need to do that once.

Comment: @InbarGazit it's literally just the code DocuSign released: https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt - the only thing I've done is populate the ds_config.ini file.

Comment: ok, and you get a consent required error back from the API?

Comment: Yes, when I run the code it states consent required and emits a url, which I copy-paste into a browser.  The first time this happened it prompted me to accept the permissions, but subsequent times I pasted the URL it immediately redirected me to the rediretct URI.

Comment: Given that I'm trying just to extract all envelopes in a certain status, regardless of owner, is the JWT/system integration method I'm using even the right way to go about it?

Comment: well, in general we don't recommend using JWT unless you have no choice. Do you only have one DocuSign account/user? I wonder if when you log in you use one user, but the GUID you put in the ds_config.ini is for another user.

Comment: I set up a developer account with a sandbox in docusign, so i literally only have one user in the entire system.  For my stated purpose, what method would you use if not JWT.

Comment: you can use Auth Code Grant (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant)

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant this is Python code example. Number 3 is what you need.

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant/blob/master/app/eg003_list_envelopes.py the specific one you need

Comment: So auth code grant is good for situations where I want an unattended process to download envelopes from docusign without a user needing to be involved?

Comment: nope, if it's unattended, that won't work

Comment: however, you can login one time, and then you'll have a refresh token that can be used for a long time.

Comment: So what is the preferred method for an unattended process as I described, is it JWT?

Comment: yes, it is JWT. We need to figure out why you keep getting this error. can you please email apihelp@docusign.com and provide your account information?

Answer (score 0):

When you update all the needed configuration for the code example (https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt) it's important to remember to set the GUID for the userId in ds_config.ini file. That can be found by going to DocuSign Admin and checking the user in the users list. This is the relevant line:

```
DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID={IMPERSONATED_GUID}
```

Updating this with the correct user that corresponds to the login you used when granting consent would resolve this issue.